# How to update multiple records using put method in web api

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am using web api put method in mvc.
I have multiple records of json object array.

How to I update multiple records using put method in web api?

Comment: For future reference, it really helps if you create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Check out [the MDN docs for binding Collections with ASP.Net Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-3.0#collections). Let me know if that's what you're looking for

Comment: Are u using Entity Framework? and what you updating, only one status? or many properties?(this is use to determine your parameter)

Comment: Yes, I am using Entity Framework and I want to update entire json list in web api.